# How to get back default ubuntu theme from macos theme

Tags: 22.04

I have changed theme  into macos but now wanted to get back  default ubuntu layout or theme.
So please help me to do that .

Comment: Please provide OS/product/release details, as your question is most unclear. You mention Ubuntu (GNOME desktop), Lubuntu (LXQt) & Debian (*unknown*) and haven't provided release details so are we to guess?

Comment: I am using ubuntu but i changed the theme  and everything of mac os .

Comment: now  i wanted to get  back  those ubuntu  theme or displat

Comment: You've still not cleared up details; what release of Ubuntu?  Why did you tag *Debian* and Lubuntu.  Ubuntu and Lubuntu use different DEs & have different defaults (inc. themes); so please edit your question providing release details & so it doesn't contradict.  (*Ubuntu Desktop default themes can vary on release too, and given we don't know what release you're using, are we to guess?*)